# PHP - strlen() doesn't work correctly after removing emojis from string

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
b‍♀️‍♀️b
```

After removing the smilies and special chars:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^ -\x{2122}]\s+|\s*[^ -\x{2122}]/u','',$str);
$str = trim($str);
```

...

```
strlen($str);
```

gives me 8 instead of 2, why and how to fix this?

Comment: Multi Byte Character Set? Maybe

Comment: And it's self explanatory to understand what this means?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/BDFJ4

Comment: How exactly does it solve the problem? I just need the result to be 2 and nothin else!

Comment: Tell `mb_strlen()` what character set you are using https://3v4l.org/TUpjt

Comment: I don't get it, why is it 2 when I don't have any smilies inside the string to begine with? Does adding smilies change the character set? Is it always UTF-32 when there are no smilies?

Comment: Because the 2 `b` are in fact 4 bytes each as its a 4 byte char set

Comment: It still doesn't work correctly, when I only have those smilies without the b's then mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-32') gives me 1 instead of 0, wth is all this crap

Comment: Between the  and ♀ is a "zero width joiner" codepoint that is not matched by your regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression is not sufficient to remove all special characters. A special debugger shows which characters are still present after the preg_replace.

```
"b\u{200d}\u{200d}b"
```

or as 8 bytes

```
"b\xe2\x80\x8d\xe2\x80\x8db"
```

The [characters \u{200d}](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+200D) are in the original string between the emojis. Removing these characters for the specific example here is not difficult.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^ -\x{2122}]\s+|\s*[^ -\x{2122}]|\x{200d}/u','',$str);
```

However, this is not a solution if other special characters can also occur.

Comment: But it's still a solution to the question, thanks!